# JsPlumb´: if source `div `is child of `div` with `position:absolute` -> targed endpint wrong drawn

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsplumb

I have the following setup: https://jsfiddle.net/b6phv6dk/1/

It basically contains two blue `div` elements with jsPlumb connectors.

The source `div` is the child of a third black `div` element that has an offset of 100px from the top, applied with `position: absolute;`.

It seems like jsPlumb takes the difference in position of the black `div` to the blue source div ( which is 0px ) and draws the connection according to this absolute position of the blue source `div` ( because the `targed endpoint would be right if the blue source`div`would be at the global position`0px 0px`):

If I remove the `position: absolute;` from the `blackDiv` the target endpoint is drawn correct, but I have a setup where I have nested `div` elements that hold their relative position to each other by:

```
.item {
    position: absolute;
     top: value; 
    left: value
}
```

[image: screenshot 47]

Answer (score 1):

Try encapsulating all elements in a container:

```
<div id="container">

  <div class="blackDiv">
    <div id="item_left" class="item"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="item_right" class="item" style="top: 100px; left:250px;"></div>

</div>
```

and setting it on the jsplumb instance:

```
jsPlumb.setContainer("container");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b6phv6dk/2/